# inappbrowser not working properly on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I am using inappbrowser plugin on my cordova 3.4.0 iOS project. I am trying to show toolbar so that user can back to app. But no toolbar is showing.

My code is

```
window.open("http://www.youtube.com/embed/OFFXHbjVZ7A?html5=1",'_blank','location=no,closebuttoncaption=Done,toolbar=yes,toolbarposition=top');
```

i tried with but no luck

```
var ref = window.open('http://www.youtube.com/embed/OFFXHbjVZ7A?html5=1', '_blank', 'location=yes');
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert(event.url); });
```

log is

```
2014-03-31 16:04:35.549 Survey[3202:60b] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2014-03-31 16:04:35.617 Survey[3202:60b] Unlimited access to network resources
2014-03-31 16:04:37.562 Survey[3202:60b] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2014-03-31 16:04:38.557 Survey[3202:60b] Finished load of: file:///var/mobile/Applications/CBFA4CF5-ABFD-41BD-8832-064022B1699D/Survey.app/www/index.html
2014-03-31 16:04:41.698 Survey[3202:60b] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2014-03-31 16:04:53.948 Survey[3202:60b] Finished load of: http://www.youtube.com/embed/OFFXHbjVZ7A?html5=1
```

`It is showing video but no back button`

Basically i need to back to app.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm getting the same result even if I use target="_system"!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this on your system - check for cordova_plugins.js. See if it is being populated with the clobber data(its a property in the field, dont have to get into details of it). If not then go to the terminal and in your project folder run 
"cordova prepare". If you dont have cordova cli installed use - "phonegap build ios".
It should populate cordova_plugin.js with your inappbrowser clobbber data.

You would find cordova_plugin.js in platform/ios/asset/www/

Comment: yes,it is being populated with the clobber data into cordova_plugins.js but no alert. no back button

Comment: Can you paste what data is being populated in it and the path of the file.

Comment: I am running out of suggestions. Did you add the access origin policy in the config.xml file? I am not sure if that could be a problem.
<access origin ="*">

Comment: What you could do is - build it , run it using weinre debugger and using the console run this javascript - 
var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert("holla amigo"); });

To initiate the inappbrowser

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your inappbrowser plugin is being loaded? If you are getting the same result on _system, then I guess your inappbrowser is not loading.Most of the time , developers face this problem. What you could do is use this example instead of your line of code -

```
var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert(event.url); });
```

If the alert fires up , we have a bigger fish to fry else we have to find why your plugin is not being loaded. You are doing this locally or using phonegap build?

Comment: Yes, you are right!! My inappbrowser plugin is not loaded. I used your code and get no alert. I am using PhoneGap build.

Comment: what can i do to load my inappbrowser plugin?

Comment: Are you using phonegap build or are you trying to do this in your system itself?

Comment: If you are using this on your system - check for cordova_plugins.js

Comment: it is a phonegap 3.4.0 project. I am using xcode 5 and testing on iPod touch

Comment: do you mean platforms/ios/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser/www/inappbrowser.js by cordova_plugins.js or platforms/ios/www/cordova.js?

Comment: No kabir . I dont mean the inappbrowser.js. Just find cordova_plugin.js. It will be in your ios -assets-www folder

Answer (score 0):

Although this question isn't new, the answer has changed with the 1.0.0 (Apr 15, 2015) release of InAppBrowser: use cordova.InAppBrowser.open rather than window.open.

I'm not sure the full scope, but at the very least it's relevant to Cordova 5.0.0 building for iOS 8.